# Why does Ruby use =~ instead of ~= for matching operator?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this stupid question about matching operator in Ruby. Why did Ruby make the matching operator `=~` instead of `~=`? Is there a historical, psychological or other considerations of making the former instead of the later?

I couldn't found any info on this, and I need to make sense about this because I keep typing the wrong thing due to other operator such as `+=`, `-=`, `!=`, `>=` and `<=` place the `=` on the right of the other operator, while `=~` is the opposite.

Please enlight me.

Comment: I guess it's to keep the same operator as in Perl

Comment: Perl used `=~` and `!~` from the very beginning, i.e. 1987.

Comment: And, AFAIK, `~` for pattern matching came from AWK which is where Perl got the idea.

Comment: Maybe the language monks should add some aliases for the benefit of those of us who can't keep the order straight. This would only be done where the other way around is not used and can't be used, such as `~=`, `=<`, '=!` and so on. :-)

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is that it is more consistant. They are several 'equal' and 'match' operators. For instance:

`=~` for 'matches'

`!~` for 'does not match'

`==` for 'equals'

`!=` for 'does not equal'

Comment: I've been learning Bash lately, and bash uses `=~` so i'd agree with consistency's sake

Answer (score 3):

Also from a far higher level prospective if you think about the way you would read these symbols in words it makes prefect sense:

- `+= -=` are basically saying `a = a + b` or `a = a - b` obviously the
  addition(`+`) or subtraction(`-`) must happen prior to the
  assignment(`=`).
- As for comparison operators like `>= !=` these make sense too because
  you are asking is `a` greater than(`>`) or equal to(`=`) `b`or does
  `a` not(`!`) equal(`=`) `b` so why not write it that way.
- In the same way `~=` would be like saying does `a` pattern(`~`)
  match(`=`) `b` when what you want is `=~` which would read does `a`
  match(`=`) pattern(`~`) `b`.

If you read them as words it become fairly succinct.

Comment: ...and if we write `(pattern) =~ (string)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland fair enough for the `Regexp` class I have to go with the other answer as it falls more in line with consistency but if you look at the C source all `String#=~` does is transpose the arguments and call the same method(`rb_reg_match`) as `Regexp#=~`. Although `Regexp` handles the assignment of variables in the pattern where as `String` does not.